# {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerShipping()}} didn't work in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates

I added

```
{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerShipping()}}
```

to email template but it didn't work. However, if using

```
{{var order.getCustomerShipping()}}
```

it is working, what's different?

My Magento version is 2.1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Magento 2,

Use of  `htmlescape` has Deprecated from email template.

You can find info about those from core file,

`vendor/magento/magento2-base/CHANGELOG.md` find **2.0.0.0-dev02** release note from this file.

```
Eliminated remnants of `htmlescape` implementation
```

So your  `{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerShipping()}}` code is not working.
You must use, `{{var order.getCustomerShipping()}}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after migrating from Magento 1. The solution is to install a fresh Magento 2 and copy the E-Mail template from there or copy the parts you need.